# How to get current to the load with a buffer Op Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier, buffer

I am reading about voltage buffer Op Amp configurations and it seems like there is no current through the circuit, specifically the load. So why would you want to get a specific voltage to the load if there is no current? I guess I am just confused by the reasoning why you would use a buffer op amp setup.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no current from v<sub>S</sub> to R<sub>L</sub>. The op amp, however, is capable of sourcing current from its supply (some models more than others), and it is this current that flows through R<sub>L</sub>.

Comment: Oh, interesting. I didn't know that. Thanks!

Comment: What's not shown on the diagram is the power connections to the op-amp. Amplifiers don't _generate_ power - they use a small signal to create a larger signal (voltage or current or both) from another source of power (the battery or power-supply).

Comment: The opamp - and in particular the shown circuit with 100% feedback - works as a "voltage-controlled voltage source (VCVS) having a very large (idealized: infinite) input resistance and a very low (idealized: zero) output resistance.